# add_rewrite_rule - Page Slug from "/foo-bar/" to "/foo/bar/"

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, slug, rewrite-rules

## I need foo-bar to become foo/bar instead:

//domain.com**/foo-bar**   »   //domain.com**/foo/bar**

---

I'm rebuilding a website that is currently in a home-brew CMS. They have a few pages with children, but the parent page URL does not match the children. The parent URLs were changed but the children were never updated.

**Expected Structure:**
//domain.com/parent/
//domain.com/parent/child

**Current Structure:**
//domain.com/parentpage/       (*changed from /parent/*)
//domain.com/parent/child

I could just create a page for each but I'm trying to avoid having empty/unused pages.

**What I'm hoping to do is just create //domain.com/parent-child/ and rewrite the URL to match, but I can't get my rules to take priority over an existing rule**.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what rewrites can accomplish?

---

## add_rewrite_rule

**Matched Query:**

```
pagename=foo-bar&page=
```

**My Attempts:**
I expected somethig like one of these to be my solution, but I've tried a dozen different minor variations without success:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^foo/bar', 'index.php?pagename=foo-bar', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule( '(foo)/(bar)', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]-$matches[2]&page=', 'top');
```

**Default rule my page is matching:**

```
add_rewrite_rule( '(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]')
```

Comment: What about creating a category "foo" with page name "bar"?

Comment: That could work too, but seems more confusing than just having an empty page.

Comment: Your first attempt works as expected for me, latest WP, no plugins, 2016 theme.

Comment: I noticed my rewrites were not flushing when I expected them to so that's a possibility. But I actually just got a more dynamic version working based on a post you answered. =)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250837/understanding-add-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is what I ended up with after finding this post:
[Understanding add_rewrite_rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250837/understanding-add-rewrite-rule)

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^foo/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo-$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can change rules not only with `add_rewrite_rule` but also with a filter(s) (one - general I am using in all common cases is `rewrite_rules_array`). You will receive an array of rewrite rules (and you expect to return it back), but you can change it slightly.

And (minute of advertisement) - you can also use [debug bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) and [debug bar rewrite rules](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-rewrite-rules/) panel to check your rules against your test URLs to see priority/matches etc. I am the author of this plugin (debug bar rewrite rules panel) and will be glad for a feedback.